# Como obter qual viewcell o usuário deu o click, e pegar um texto de uma label que esta nesta mesma view cell atravez do commandParameter?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm

Tenho o seguinte código na minha view

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          HasUnevenRows="true"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell x:Name="cell">
                <StackLayout x:Name="item" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,5" HeightRequest="110" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <BoxView WidthRequest="8" BackgroundColor="#381F72"/> 
                    <Image Source="{Binding img}"/>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding nome}" 
                               FontSize="18" 
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               TextColor="#381F72"
                               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding QtdServicos}" 
                               FontSize="14"
                               TextColor="#381F72"
                               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,15,0,0">
                            <StackLayout x:Name="Item" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ok}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Avaliacoes}"
                                       FontSize="14"
                                       TextColor="#03FD9B"
                                       VerticalOptions="End"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Button Text="CONTRATAR"
                                    Padding="5"
                                    Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                    BackgroundColor="#03FD9B"
                                    TextColor="White"
                                    HeightRequest="20"
                                    FontSize="10"
                                    CornerRadius="5"
                                    BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListView}, Path=BindingContext}"
                                    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ContratarCommand, Source={x:Reference ContactView}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

e a minha view model..

```
 private Command<object> _ContratarCommand;
    public Command<object> ContratarCommand => _ContratarCommand ?? (_ContratarCommand = new Command<object>(ContratarCommandExecute));


    async void ContratarCommandExecute(object value)
    {
        try
        {
            // Aqui o VALUE vem a lista contendo todos os viewCell na tela com as suas respectivas propriedades.

            await NavigationService.Current.NavigateTo(new ChatView(...,...));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Entre em contato com nossa equipe de suporte!", ex.Message, "ok");
        }

    }
```

eu queria obter apenas o conteúdo da viewcell onde esta o botão clicado, e nao todos os itens da minha classe vinculada a listview no ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
tem como fazer isso, oque preciso mudar no meu código? 
desde já obrigado.
meu primeiro projeto então me perdoem!

Comment: Para quem tiver algum interesse, eu consegui resolver, o problema era que na minha view eu estava referenciando no bindingContext do button a minha list view aqui nesta linha,  
BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListView}, Path=BindingContext}"

eu mudei e passei a referenciar a viewCell, deu um x:name para ela txtCell e referenciei ela assim

BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference txtcell}, Path=BindingContext}"

e veio somente o item da viewCell e nao uma lista de todos os items da listView

Comment: Olá, se sua dúvida foi solucionada, por favor feche a pergunta.